# Remove floating misplaced dot in tufte book contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tufte-book

This is my code I see a dot under Contexto, which is the only chapter in the contents. Help appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{tufte-book}
 \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}%


\title[]{%\thanks{
\Huge Documento}
%}
\author[Ruth Lazcoz S\'aez]{\large Ruth Lazcoz S\'aez}
\publisher{30644798N}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myhuge{\@setfontsize\Huge{24}{60}}
\newcommand\mylarge{\@setfontsize\Huge{15}{50}}
\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{\chapter{\myhuge {#1}}}
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{\section{\mylarge {#1}}}

\makeatother 

\newcommand{\monthyear}{%
  \ifcase\month\or Enero\or Febrero\or Marzo\or Abril\or Mayo\or Junio\or
  Julio\or Agosto\or Septiembre\or Octubre\or Noviembre\or
  Diciembre\fi\space\number\year
}

\newcommand{\openepigraph}[2]{%
  %\sffamily\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont
  \begin{fullwidth}
  \sffamily\large
  \begin{doublespace}
  \noindent\allcaps{#1}\\% epigraph
  \noindent\allcaps{#2}% author
  \end{doublespace}
  \end{fullwidth}}


\newcommand{\blankpage}{\newpage\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}

\usepackage{units}


% Generates the index
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[permil]{overpic}
\begin{document}

% Front matter
\frontmatter

% r.1 blank page
\blankpage

% v.2 epigraphs
\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}
\openepigraph{%
quote}{--name}\vfill

% r.3 full title page
\maketitle


% v.4 copyright page
\newpage
\begin{fullwidth}
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
%Copyright \copyright\ \the\year\ \thanklessauthor

\par\smallcaps{Bilbao/Leioa (Bizkaia)}
\par\textit{Esta versi\'on, \monthyear}
%
\end{fullwidth}

% r.5 contents
\tableofcontents*

%\listoffigures

%\listoftables

% r.7 dedication
\cleardoublepage
~\vfill
\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\fontsize{18}{22}\selectfont\itshape
\nohyphenation
Dedicated to the adamant golfer
\end{doublespace}
\vfill
\vfill
\renewcommand{\thepart}{} %Removes the counting in roman numerals before the part name
\cleardoublepage

\mychapter{Contexto}
\end{document}
```